# How do you turn off Logging in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My console is getting filled up with unwanted log messages from ChromeDriver and IEDriver.

[image]

I've tried: `Console.SetOut(TextWriter.NULL);` but that doesn't work. I've tried various implementations of `driver.setCapabilities(LOGGING, NOOOOO)` but nothing works.

Answer (score 8):

Not knowing exactly which language bindings you're using, it's a little challenging to give you the exact code to eliminate those messages, but in the case of the drivers for IE and Chrome, you want to get the `--silent` switch passed on the command line. For the .NET bindings, that means setting properties on the respective service classes and passing those into the driver constructor. For IE, that code would look like

```
InternetExplorerDriverService service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
```

Similarly for Chrome, you'd want something like

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
```